# QFileDialog::getSaveFileName not always returning extension

Tags: qt, filedialog

Under Qt 5.1.0 on Windows7 I'm using the following code to get a project name:

```
QString filter = "Project Files (*.proj)";
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "New Project", QString(),
                                                      "Project Files (*.proj)", &filter);
```

On return, when running under Qt Creator, I get the project name with the ".proj" extension (e.g. "foo.proj"). But when I deploy the application and run it, the extension is not appended (e.g. "foo"). Any idea why?

Note the executable is deployed on a Windows XP-x86 system as a 32-bit executable. It was developed on a Windows7-x64 system using Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 505 MB).

Perhaps QTBUG-27186 didn't properly correct the issue?

Comment: Deploy where? Same computer, or different one? If different, which OS?

Comment: Look at https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27186 It seems a resolved bug.

Comment: Does the user have the default "hide extensions for known file types" enabled in windows and that is not enabled on your dev box?